# Javascript - button inside a table -> inserting TextContent

Tags: javascript, dom

I need some help as I was trying to create a table by iterating through an array. With each itereation I want to create 4 row at which one row shall be a button.

I have managed to create a button however, I cannot manipulate the TextContent of the button:

Here is my JS Code:
the array contain an object so I have to itereation:

````
currentLibary.forEach(function(item,index){
    let newRow=myTable.insertRow();

//--------second iteration to acces each key:value pair. **With each iteration a new cell will be created.**-> last row has a button. -----------------
    currentLibary.forEach(function () {
        let NewCell=newRow.insertCell();
        if(count == 0){
            NewCell.innerHTML=currentLibary[iteration].title;

        }
        if(count == 1){
            NewCell.innerHTML=currentLibary[iteration].author;

        }

        if(count == 2){
            NewCell.innerHTML=currentLibary[iteration].pages;

        }
        if(count == 3){
            let button=document.createElement('button');
            button.type="button";
            NewCell.innerHTML='<button type="button"></button>'<----- I cannot change the 
                                                                      text inside the 
                                                                      button. via 
                                                                      textContent.  
            

        }

        count=count+1;
    })
    count=0
    iteration=iteration +1
});```
````

Comment: Could you share the `currentLibary` data you're looping over?

Comment: To change the text of the button, you can use `innerText` property. 
https://jsfiddle.net/jxst1epg/2/

Comment: console.log(currentLibary) (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]0: {title: "The TryHard", author: "Always", pages: "20", read: "Read"}1: {title: "The Don", author: "Myself", pages: "1", read: "Not Read"}2: {title: "Naruto", author: "Shipuden", pages: "1", read: "Not Read"}3: {title: "TestLauf", author: "Numero", pages: "2", read: "Not Read"}

this is my current array.

innerText does not work neither does textContent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the `textContent` or `innerText` of a string.

What you need to do is set the `textContent` on the `button` variable, which is an `HTMLButtonElement` object, and then use `NewCell.append(button)` to add the button to the cell.

```
let button = document.createElement('button');
button.type = 'button';
button.textContent = currentLibary[iteration].read;

NewCell.append(button);
```

There were more things in the code that need some improvement or are prone to break. I took the liberty to address some of those issues and give feedback on how to use and implement certain functions. I hope you find these hints useful and intend this as constructive feedback.

```
/**
 * Using forEach exposes the current item (item) that is being looped over.
 * This can be very useful in accessing the value of the current iteration.
 */
currentLibary.forEach(function(item) {
  /** 
   * Use const instead of let when you know that the value will never change.
   * In this case row will always be a row.
   * Using let could hint that the value might change somewhere in the future.
   */
  const row = myTable.insertRow();

  /**
   * Destructuring allows you to access properties of an object like variables.
   * The title, author, pages and read property of each item are now available as variables inside the scope of the function.
   */
  const { title, author, pages, read } = item;

  /**
   * The forEach loop doesn't make sense here and will break your code whenever currentLibary doesn't have 4 items in length.
   * Instead use a classic for loop.
   */
  for (let count = 0; count < 4; count++) { 
    const cell = row.insertCell();

    /**
     * The switch statement is also a good candidate here.
     * Though this might just be a preference. Your choice.
     */
    switch(count) {
      case 0:
        /**
         * Since the title, and the other variables too, don't contain any HTML,
         * use textContent or innerText instead.
         */
        cell.textContent = title;
        break;
      case 1:
        cell.textContent = author;
        break;
      case 2:
        cell.textContent = pages;
        break;
      case 3:
        const button = document.creatElement('button');
        button.type = 'button';
        button.textContent = read; // Set the text here..
        cell.append(button); // ..and add the button to the cell.
        break;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey man, thank you very much for your effort. Yesterday I worked till midnight and actually started to use the for loop as you mentioned. Your solution is correct and worked so far